# Calling Thread.sleep inside an actor

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, actor

I have a function retry which basically looks like this (simplified):

```
object SomeObject {
 def retry[T](n: Int)(fn: => T): Option[T] = {
    val res = try {
      Some(fn)
    } catch {
      case _: Exception => None
    }

    res match {
      case Some(x) => Some(x)
      case None => 
        if (n > 1) 
          //make it sleep for a little while
          retry(n - 1)(fn) 
        else None
    }
  }
}
```

I need to make some pause between the attempts. As I was told, it's not acceptable to call `Thread.sleep(123)` inside an actor:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  //......
  def someFunc = {
    Thread.sleep(456) // it's not acceptable in an actor, there is another way to do it
  }

}
```

Obviously, I don't know whether or not a client will use `SomeObject.retry` inside an actor:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  //......
  def someFunc = {
    SomeObject.retry(5)(someRequestToServer) // ops, SomeObject.retry uses Thread.sleep!
  }

}
```

So if I just add:

```
res match {
      case Some(x) => Some(x)
      case None => 
        if (n > 1) 
          //make it sleep for a little while
          Thread.sleep(123) // ops, what if it's being called inside an actor by a client?!
          retry(n - 1)(fn) 
        else None
    }
  }
```

it won't be sensible, will it? If not, what do I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, calling `Thread.sleep` is a bad idea as in an actor system threads are normally a limited resource shared between Actors. You do not want an Actor calling sleep and hogging a Thread from other Actors.

What you should do instead is use the `Scheduler` (see [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/scheduler.html)) to have your actor sent a message to itself sometime in the future to retry. To do this, you would have to move the retry code out of `SomeObject` and into the `Actor`

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  import context.system.dispatcher

  def receive = {
    case DoIt(retries) if retries > 0 => 
      SomeObject.attempt(someRequestToServer) match {
        case Some(x) => ...
        case None => 
          context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5.seconds, self, DoIt(retries - 1))
      }
  }

}
```

Then if you were using `SomeObject.try` outside of an Actor System

```
def attempt(retries: Int) = {
  SomeObject.attempt(someRequestToServer) match {
    case Some(x) => ...
    case None if retries > 0 => {
      Thread.sleep(123)
      attempt(retries - 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Where `SomeObject.attempt` is:

```
object SomeObject {
  def attempt[T](fn: => T): Option[T] =
    try {
      Some(fn)
    } catch {
      case _: Exception => None
    }
}
```

Comment: if you move all code from `SomeObject.attempt` out of it, what code is left in the method `SomeObject.attempt`?

Comment: Not a lot. All that would be left in the `attempt` would be the `try` `catch` in your `retry` method that returns a `None` or a `Some`. Because the code to wait/retry in an Actor System is quite a lot different from the code to wait/retry in a purely multi-threaded system it is very hard to get any reusable common code out of the two.

Comment: could you please show the full example? I can't figure out what should be in 1) SomeObject.attempt 2) def attempt (...) case Some(x) =>...

Comment: I've added the `SomeObject.attempt` method. The remaining `...` are the places where enough retries have happened to get a result. I don't know the semantics behind your code, so don't know what you would want to do here.

Comment: why does attempt have "n" parameter if it doesn't use it?